# How to add two data attribute check in cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

Ex:

```
<div data-component="tab" data-value="first_tab">
</div>
```

How can I get data-component="tab" and  data-value="first_tab" together in cypress command?
Like I want to access select box inside first_tab and I want to be more context specific and write a more readable code:
What I have tried is below (which is syntactically wrong)

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab" data-value="first_tab"] [data-component="select_box"]').click()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cypress follows the jQuery convention so this should work:

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]').click()
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]').within(() =>
    cy.get('[data-component="select_box"]').click()
    })
```

Cypress Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Get-in-within