# How to get multiple elements with data-cy attributes

Tags: cypress

I have a table with all cells marked with the data-cy attribute as so: `[data-cy="cell-${row}-${column}]`.

Individually I have no trouble to get each cell with the classic `cy.get`, for example `cy.get("[data-cy=cell-2-17]").click()`, but I try to test the click on multiple cells holding the control key but I couldn't achieve that.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763473/how-to-add-two-data-attribute-check-in-cypress) it says to simply concat the selectors passed to cy.get but it didn't work for me, I tried with and without the " around the data-cy names:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="cell-2-17"][data-cy="cell-4-10"]').click({multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})`
```

Could you tell me how to get multiple elements using the data-cy attribute?

Comment: You can get the elements one by one on the basis of index. Does that work for your use case ?

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how you get element one by one and then apply a click with control key on each element (what I tried to achieve is to do a multiple cell selection, this being done in real life by clicking on multiple cells while the control key is down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concatenate selectors (without space or + between), it means the element must have all those selectors.

There's not really a concise way to provide a list of required attributes.

Two things that help are wildcards and filters

```js
const cellsWanted = ['cell-2-17', 'cell-4-10']

cy.get('[data-cy^="cell-"]')   // wildcard anything that starts with "cell-"
  .filter((index, el) => cellsWanted.some(cell => el.getAttribute('data-cy') === cell))
  .click({multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})`
```

---

**Multiple selectors with comma between**

Just found an easier way using [jquery multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="cell-2-17"], [data-cy="cell-4-10"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .click({multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have though of it earlier - I only ever used it for either/or type selection but it also works the way it's named, surprisingly!